# Apache Kafka Consumer Election

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Lets say we have two consumers for a topic with one partition. At first, first consumes messages from the topic and second remains idle. If first fails, second takes over and starts consuming the messages.

When the first again comes alive, will it again start consuming messages and make the second idle?

How to achieve this?

Comment: There is no master and slave relationship between consumers

Answer (score 0):

Consumers are a part of a consumer group, defined by the consumer's `group.id`. For `n` partitions, the max number of active consumers in a consumer group is `n`. You can have more, but they will be idle.

> For example, imagine a topic with 6 partitions. If you have 6
> consumers in a consumer group, each consumer will read from 1
> partition. If you have 12, six of the consumers will remain idle while
> the other six consume from 1 partition. If you have 3 consumers, each
> consumer will read from 2 partitions.

In your case, for a topic with **1** partition, only **1** consumer for each consumer group can be actively consuming at a time. If you have **2** consumers in your consumer group, then `consumer-1` will consume all messages from the single partition. If that consumer fails, `consumer-2` will start consuming at the last known offset of `consumer-1`. If `consumer-1` comes back online, it will remain idle until `consumer-2` fails. All consumers are treated equally.

Comment: Thanks for your help Shawn. Is there a way to make consumer-2 die when consumer-1 is up manually or by modifying any configuration?

Comment: No problem! It depends totally how you are running your consumers. For example, if they are in kubernetes or docker, you would just have the container always running so `consumer-1` just automatically restarts if it fails. There's no real reason to have have `consumer-2` down if `consumer-1` is running if you can just make `consumer-1` restart on failure.